# MySQL delete specified rows from a table when the data from yesterday matches the data from today

Tags: mysql, database, join, inner-join

I have some data stored in a MySQL table called MyTable like this:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
|    my_id |    amount | updated             |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
|   105415 |        81 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |
|   105414 |        33 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |
|   220801 |       240 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |
|   105411 |       118 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |
|   105411 |       118 | 2013-02-12 00:00:00 |
|   220801 |       240 | 2013-02-12 00:00:00 |
|   105414 |        33 | 2013-02-11 00:00:00 |
|   105415 |        81 | 2013-02-11 00:00:00 |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

What I would like to do is delete all the rows from yesterday (2013-02-12) that have the same my_id and amount as today (2013-02-13).

I know how to select all the data from today:

`SELECT * FROM 'MyTable' WHERE 'updated' = CURDATE()`

I know how to select all the data from yesterday:

`SELECT * FROM 'MyTable' WHERE 'updated' = CURDATE()-1`

I know the syntax for the DELETE command (`DELETE FROM 'MyTable' WHERE...`).

**How do I delete the rows where the my_id and amount match for yesterday and today?**

In the example given, I would want to delete these rows:

```
|   105411 |       118 | 2013-02-12 00:00:00 |
|   220801 |       240 | 2013-02-12 00:00:00 |
```

And I would want to keep these rows:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
|    my_id |    amount | updated             |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
|   105415 |        81 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |
|   105414 |        33 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |
|   220801 |       240 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |
|   105411 |       118 | 2013-02-13 00:00:00 |


|   105414 |        33 | 2013-02-11 00:00:00 |
|   105415 |        81 | 2013-02-11 00:00:00 |
+----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Instead of handling the symptoms, fix the reason: Why are you generating such a duplicate entry set? Use an unique constraint on my_id and amount and update just the date in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`-Clause while saving the data.

Comment: dognose, I have fixed my script as you suggested but it still leaves me with a database to clean up which needs the query from my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
DELETE M
FROM MyTable M
    INNER JOIN MyTable M2 ON
        M.My_Id = M2.My_Id AND  
        M.amount = M2.amount AND  
        M2.Updated = DATE_ADD(M.Updated, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Here is the updated Fiddle with your sample data above: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e288/1

And the Results after the Delete:

```
MY_ID   AMOUNT  UPDATED
105415  81      February, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000
105414  33      February, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000
220801  240     February, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000
105411  118     February, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000
105414  33      February, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000
105415  81      February, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

Good luck.

Comment: Did you miss "and m.my_id = m2.my_id" ?

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen -- great catch -- didn't realize those were equal!  I updated the answer above.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! However, for more precise to the answer, it would be good to change 'M2.Updated = DATE_ADD(M.Updated, INTERVAL 1 DAY)' to 'AND M2.Updated = CURDATE() AND M.Updated = CURDATE()-1'

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen -- If OP literally means yesterday (and not previous day), then yes, you're approach is safer.  I presumed OP meant previous day and needed to cleanup historical data comparing current day to previous day.  No worries though -- thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thank-you sgeddes for your solution and for pointing me towards SQL Fiddle (I hadn't come across this site before and it is great!).  I am a little puzzled about the difference between CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(x, INTERVAL 1 DAY).  Can you expand on this for me?

Comment: @user1464409 -- if you just want to compare today (2/13) with yesterday, you can use CURDATE() as SurasinTancharoen suggested.  However, if you have historical data (last week for example) that you also need to cleanup, then use what I posted above.  Let me know if you have trouble and I'll update the answer with CURDATE().  Best of luck!

Comment: Got you!  Thank-you very much, no need to update your answer.

Comment: @user1464409 -- here is the Fiddle (yeah, I love that tool too!) for the CURDATE() solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/840f0/1 -- with your sample data, they both yield the same results.  But again, the CURDATE() solution will only DELETE records from 2/12 :)

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that if the value in one of the columns is NULL then the match does not work.  Is there a way around this?  For instance lets say the value "240" in the amount column is replaced by NULL for every instance of "240".  If I now run the script you gave the rows with NULL in them do not match.  I am guess this is something to do with the special nature of NULL within the database.

Comment: @user1464409 -- if you don't care about the amounts being the same (meaning one can be 240 and the other can be NULL) and all you care about is the ID being the same, then you can remove the amount from the JOIN and it should work fine.  Alternatively, you could use IFNULL -- more Fiddle :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8b21/1

Comment: This is what I meant: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5dd1/1 (See both of the 240's have been replaced by NULL - but now the lines are not deleted from the final result, there should only be one of them - the one with the latest date).

Comment: I think this solves it for the NULL values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2d1d/1 (basically add a false value which will never be in the column for the IFNULL statement)

Comment: @user1464409 -- sorry, stepped away -- yep, that should do it!

Answer (score 2):

A bit modify from @sgeddes 's answer, I think this a bit more precise to your answer:

Anyways, please give credit as correct answer to @sgeddes 's answer since his answer guided to this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM MyTable AS t1, MyTable as t2
WHERE t1.updated = CURDATE()-1
  AND t2.updated =  CURDATE()
  AND t2.my_id = t1.my_id
  And t2.amount = t1.amount;
```

If you have a primary key, you can also use this (which is my prefer SQL)

```
DELETE FROM MyTable 
WHERE  updated = CURDATE()-1 
  AND (my_id,amount) in (select my_id,amount 
                         from MyTable
                         where updated = CURDATE());
```